# drupal---how to make this module

Tags: php, drupal-6

now,i want to custom a module by myself,expect someone can do me some favors. many thanks. the following is my thinking and some ways i did.

i use CCK module creating two content type "**production**" and "**merchant**", the production have four field (title, production introduction, **merchant name** (which merchant the production belongs to , when you click the merchant name field,it will get to the merchant's page. and under the merchant's introduction i want to show all the productions which belongs to the merchant ). production image,) the merchant have three fields(title, merchant introduction,merchant image)

**ps**:every production only have one merchant,every merchant can have one or more productions.

the module which i want to custom can get this effect, **clicking the merchant field in production part,it will get to the merchant's page. and show all the productions which belong to the merchant under the merchant's production**). i thought maybe i use the hook_nodeapi and hook_form_alter ,node_node can get that.

Q1:how to make the database? how many fields i should created.
Q2,how to write the hook_api's part. and make sure i can't add the same name merchants.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to code a single line to accomplish this. I've done the same many times using CCK's node reference fields, the [node relationships](http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships) and [views module](http://drupal.org/project/views).

Comment: thanks for you  recommended modules.if i want to write it by myself by means of cck,how should i do?

Comment: If you really want to code it yourself, then you should not use CCK. Don't get me wrong, CCK is great. But if you like to reinvent the wheel, you should not start with a tractor. Take a look at http://drupal.org/node/231019.

Comment: nope,i use the cck, only don't use node relationships. someone told me use cck to creat two content type. then use hook_form_alter and hook_nodeapi() to alter one field in the product content type. now,i don't know how to write the hook_nodeapi()'s part.

Comment: @rik - great analogy, @runeveryday - well, now someone is telling you to just do it all in CCK - who do you believe?  Personally, I'm going to go with rik, because what he suggests is far easier than what you're trying to do.

Comment: rik, i have tried the modules you have said. but don't know how to make this step. when click the  merchant field in production part,it will get to the merchant's page. and show all the productions which belong to the merchant under the merchant's introduction

Comment: i dont' know where to set to make the show all the productions  under the merchant's introduction